# tymondesigns/jwt-auth attempt always returns false

Tags: laravel

```
$credentials = $request->only('mobile', 'code');

try {
    // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
    if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
    }
} catch (JWTException $e) {
    // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
    return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
}

// all good so return the token
return response()->json(compact('token'));
```

I bcrypt the code
who could help me,please!!!

Comment: try `if(!(JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)))`

Comment: got boolean false

Comment: and `if(JWTAuth::attempt($credentials) === false)` ?

Comment: I got the reason that I change the code to password,attemp() method work.But I want use mobile and code to authenticate user,Could you help me

Comment: if that fails try to dump the credentials, maybe you are getting them wrong from the request

Comment: look at some point laravel passport is your friend, try it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport

Comment: Thank you very much.To be honest, I had not read it.I will follow your suggestion.I solve it by  JWTAuth::fromUser($user)